# How can I create a backend that debugs C++ code?

Tags: rest, gdb, backend, remote-debugging, lldb

I’ve created a web project that allows users to enter and run C++ code online [Link](https://runcodeonline.vercel.app/). I’ve been looking into implementing a debugger but need some guidance on how to go about this.

Would love if there are any existing libraries/apis that I can use, but I couldn’t find any online so I seem stuck with using command line software like lldb or gdb.

Is this addition possible with a REST api compatible or do I have to use something like a Websocket? I would prefer to continue using a REST api for simplified deployment (I’m using Google Cloud Run to host). I know this might be difficult since REST APIs are stateless, but would it be possible using something like lldb-remote to setup persistent servers that listen to user input?

It would also help If anyone could share how sites like LeetCode implement their debugger.

My backend is currently a REST api where the code is sent, then using g++, its compiled and executed and the result is returned. It's built with Node and Express.

I’ve gotten this to somewhat work using lldb, but when breakpoints are set on the frontend, the backend will just return the state of each variable at those breakpoints. Functionality is limited as the user cannot choose typical debug actions  (step into, step over, skip etc).

Comment: If you are debugging a process with lldb or gdb, you have access to not only all its memory but through the expression evaluator you can open new libraries and call arbitrary code in them.  If you have a web interface that allows open access to a debugger connected to a process on some machine somewhere, you will need to sandbox its environment pretty carefully or you will open that machine up to attacks.